# Handle package sknw in python

Tags: python, graph

Is there any official documentation for building graphes associated to skeletons of images in python in the SKNW package?  I found this package that I've installed, however, since I'm new in python, it's not easy for me to handle the latter: https://github.com/yxdragon/sknw  .

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for using sknw:

1. just load your 2d/3d image, you can use **skimage.morphology.skeletonize_3d(img)** to get a 3d skeleton from volume data.
2. **graph = sknw.build_sknw(ske， multi=False)** to got the skeleton structure, which is a networkx object.
3. do your analysis

   **graph.node[id]['pts'] :** Numpy(x, n), coordinates of nodes points

   **graph.node[id]['o']:** Numpy(n), centried of the node

   **graph.edge(id1, id2)['pts']:** Numpy(x, n), sequence of the edge point

   **graph.edge(id1, id2)['weight']:** float, length of this edge

and you can do some graph analysis use networkx.

**I think you would be intrested in my another project [ImagePy](https://github.com/Image-Py/imagepy), which you can do many image processing operation in a UI framework, just like imagej**

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wanted the length of the edge it was graph.edge[id1][id2]['weight'] & not graph.edge**(id1, id2)**['weight']